no puedo ver los datos de una API en mi aplicación React
Hola ¿Cómo están? acá va la pregunta pero mas detallada es así: tengo una aplicación React de tipo front-end, esta se trata de celulares, los datos son los productos, estos productos son celulares ,por ende cada celular es un producto .Todos los celulares que se tienen que renderizar tanto en la sección celulares como en la Home son sacados de la end-point de la API de mercado libre, copio y pego esa URL(end-point) en el fetch de un async , la cuestión es que debo estar haciendo algo mal porque cuando estoy en la Home no están esos productos, tampoco en la sección celulares

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! no. lo que podes es hacer un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte con la parte que te da problemas...

El 1 de Julio compartiste una pregunta parecida y te respondieron igual que el comentario, para que te podamos ayudar tienes que compartir el código que tienes hecho y lo que has intentado (si es que aplica). No es necesaria compartir la carpeta, solamente copia y pega el código donde tienes el problema (el código nunca va como imagen)

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: no, debes compartir un [repro] (énfasis en mínimo) de tu problema. Ya se te ha dicho en un par de preguntas previas que debes editar tu pregunta para agregar aclaraciones/detalles.

Hola Cande, bienvenida, podes editar tu pregunta, y agregar el código que necesitas verificar, así lograrás conseguir una buena respuesta.

Hola ¿Como están? René no se bien que parte de mi código es la que tiene el problema por ejemplo se que no hay un problema en el archivo registros pero no se cual de todos los archivos es el que está mal por eso envié toda la carpeta. Bueno padaleiana voy a hacer mas detallada la pregunta

listo ya la reformulé , digan me si se entiende mejor

Si, la pregunta se entiende.. pero sin el codigo que estas usando es imposible saber si tu problema es que no traes los productos, o que los traes y no los renderizas como corresponde.. como podriamos saber tu problema sin toda esa informacion? podria responderte, tu problema es que los traes mal.. y con eso, no hacemos nada.. para poder ayudarte, empiezar por entender tu codigo. Tu llamada a la api devuelve algo?

Hola gbianchi, tengo el código de mi aplicación en github, aquí está mi link: https://github.com/Candulapop/app-React-SUCESS.git , ahí está todo mi código. No, no devuelve nada , ni los productos ni ningún mensaje en la consola
